# html/css not responding on ios devices

Tags: html, css, ios

So this is a new one for me. I've never seen anything like this. Here's the background: I have an app that's used to control an eye chart in a doctors office. Nothing fancy. You press the button marked "20/20" and it makes the 20/20 line show up on the screen. Easy enough. When I run this web app on android, Windows, and Mac COMPUTERS it works perfect in the browser. Strictly when I run it on iOS devices does it behave this way. Let me show you some pictures, then some code.

[image]

[image]

So as you can see in the images, this is what's going on. You press one button on first page load, and it works fine. By the way, Samsung galaxy s9+ on the left, iPhone 11 on the right. BUT, the kicker, is that once you go to load a separate line from a different button, it's like the first set of letters gets stuck in place and won't yield to the new letters from the subsequent button presses. The javascript is simple: "if button pressed is 20/20, show certain letters...if button pressed is 20/30, show those letters instead". But for some reason the iOS devices won't let the first letters go so they can be replaced with new letters. And it's only the letters on the right half of the div that get stuck there. I've inspected and there's no overlapping div or anything. And if there was, why would it work on every other device except strictly iOS? Here is the mark up of the HTML:

```
<div class="lineHolder">
        <button class="singleButtons singleFilter" id="singleFilter" data-size="singleFilter">1</button>
        <button class="singleButtons retinoscopy" id="retinoscopy" data-size="retinoscopy">RS</button>
        <button class="singleButtons colorPlates" id="colorPlates" data-size="colorPlates">CP</button>
        <button class="singleButtons" id="refresh" data-size="refresh">R</button>
        <div class="lineContent text">
             <p id="line1"></p>
             <p id="line2"></p>
             <p id="line3"></p>
             <p id="line4"></p>
             <p id="line5"></p>
             <p id="line6"></p>
         </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.lineHolder{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url('/images/logotranslucent.png'), linear-gradient(to top, #666 , #808080);
    background-position: right bottom, center top;
    background-size: 10%, cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .lineHolder {
        background-size: 15%, cover;
    }
}

.lineContent{
    line-height: 40px;
    align-self: center;
}

.text{
    font-family: 'Sloan';
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Just for clarity: there are 6 `<p>` tags because there can be a large group of six lines if the user wishes, but with every button press, the javascript empties every single line then inserts the correct line based on user selection. I'm not including javascript in this post because the functionality is working fine on everything except iOS devices. So I'm assuming there's something hidden or uncommon about this platform that I don't know about. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to diagnose with the code presented. There is nothing there that would affect the text that is left behind. Your css isn't anything wild and your HTML is straight forward.

Some thoughts though:

1. Consider what browsers you are using for each test
2. If it looks good in a browser ios emulator, try using the xcode emulator (if you are on a mac)
3. Check the browser specs for items in CSS and javascript to make sure its consistent across the board.

The only other thing that might coincide with your JS is the media query in your CSS. This would have to be narrowed down to whatever browser you are using on the true IOS device.

I know this is vague, but hopefully point's you in a solid direction!

Cheers,
Scotty

Comment: thanks so much for the quick reply. To add a little more background on your answer. I've tried this in safari and chrome on about 6 real world iOS devices. When I run this in a simulator, it turns up totally fine. It behaves exactly as I expect it to, similar to how the android screen looks. So I can't turn to emulators. I truly have no idea what the deal is with this

Comment: just make sure you try the xcode emulator. It's as close to actual IOS as you can get while developing locally on your machine.

Comment: Only other thing is to check that your javascript isnt just placing text over old text but actually updating the DOM with the new value. Its possible that the IOS browser is simply rendering the layers wrong (I know you checked the divs but im spit balling).

Comment: right. my javascript is literally clearing the line and setting the innerHtml to an empty string, then it's reinjecting the next line

Comment: Man that's weird

Comment: RIGHT?!?! ok, i'm glad that i'm not the only one that feels that way lol. even if you don't help me actually solve it, just hearing you say "that's weird" was enough for me :D